# How to put django model form in a ready made template

Tags: python, html, css, django, django-forms

I have a model form that allows user to post and upload pics. It works normally on a blank template. So now i want to put the form in a ready made template that has field for creating posts and upload pics.
The page looks like this:
[image: The page looks like this:]

My models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    post = models.CharField(max_length=3000)
    pic = models.ImageField(blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Forms.py

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    post = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput())
```

views.py

```
class BaseView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'base.html'

    def get(self, request):
        form = PostForm()
        posts = Post.objects.all().order_by('-created')
        users = User.objects.exclude(id=request.user.id)

        args = {'form': form,'users': users, 'posts': posts}
        return render(request, self.template_name, args)
    
    def post(self, request):
        form = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.user = request.user
            post.save()
            
            pics = form.cleaned_data['pic']
            text = form.cleaned_data['post']
            form = PostForm()
            return redirect('base')

        args = {'form': form, 'text': text, 'pics':pics}
        return render(request, self.template_name, args)
```

And in the template i want to use the fields is like this:

```
<div class="create-post">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <img src="images/users/user-1.jpg" alt="" class="profile-photo-md" />
                    <textarea name="texts" id="exampleTextarea" cols="30" rows="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Write what you wish"></textarea>
                  </div>
                </div>
                    <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5">
                  <div class="tools">
                    <ul class="publishing-tools list-inline">
                      <li><a href="#"><i class="ion-images"></i></a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Publish</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

help please if you know how i can solve this. Thank you.

Comment: Just reference your fields id in the ready made form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the form fields id by using the normal {{ form }} tag,
Inspect with browser developer tool and get the field name and id
Add the name and id to the ready made form respective input
Eg if your rendered field id for text area is id_post , add id_post as text area id .....
Also change your post modelform widget to text area to Mach your ready made form

```
 class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
         post = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea())

<textarea name="post" id="id_post" cols="30" rows="1" class="form- 
     control" placeholder="Write what you wish"></textarea>
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked for the post text but for the pic i tried everything possible but i couldn't find a way. Its showing the default choose file icon. I dont want it. Anyways thank you so much

Comment: you would have to tweak the input tag for file upload to use icon,take a look at this https://blog.benestudio.co/custom-file-upload-button-with-pure-css-5aacf39aa0a might help

Answer (score 1):

You would need to render the form fields manually as per the docs here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually

So for your template this would look something like this (sketched):

```html
<div class="create-post">
    <div class="row">
        <form action="{ url .... }" method="post">
            <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7">
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form.pic }}
                    {{ form.post }}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5">
                <div class="tools">
                    <ul class="publishing-tools list-inline">
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="ion-images"></i></a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Publish</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can specify the widgets (e.g. textarea for the post field) in your ModelForm. You can see examples here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/widgets/#specifying-widgets